# How to get "address_id" from quote?

Tags: magento-1.9, quote, shipping-address, multishipping

I'm trying to get `address_id` of `sales_flat_quote_address` table as mentioned in attached image from quote during multi-shipping checkout process but no luck. I want to use that `address_id` in following file path. Any help should be appreciated. Thanks.
File Path:-
 `/app/code/local/Mage/Shipping/Model/Carrier/Flatrate.php`

[image: sales_flat_quote_address Table]

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried these:

```
$quote->getBillingAddress()->getId(); // billing address id
$quote->getShippingAddress()->getId(); // shipping address id
```

For multi-shipping:

```
$addresses = $quote->getAllShippingAddresses();
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
    $address_id = $address->getId();
}
```

Comment: Hi. I have already tried these But issue is i'm trying to get address_id during multi-shipping checkout process, and i'm not getting it.

Comment: @Raj, I have updated my answer.

Comment: Its not working in multishipping.how can we get specific address id from quote object in multishipping

Answer (score 0):

To get the address_id from the quote address table you need to use the below code.

```
$addresses = $quote->getAllShippingAddresses();
foreach ($addresses as $address) {
  $address_id = $address->getCustomerAddressId();
}
```

This will return the address Id of the shipping address associated with a logged in customer.